# Keep DialogFlow session maintain for 24 hrs

Tags: c#, session, bots, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I need to maintain a DialogFlow session for 24 hrs. So, whenever a user returns back after sometime in between of any chatbot flow, DialogFlow starts back with normal flow till 24hrs.

Comment: In Dialogflow limits [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#table) you can find info that session is kept for 30 mins from last activity: `A session is a conversation between an end-user and a Dialogflow agent. A session remains active and its data is stored for 30 minutes after the last request is sent for the session.` There is possibility for review this session but using `Dialogflow CX` and details you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/session#long-lasting). Please provide your scenario and if you are limited to DialogFlow ES only

Comment: Yes, currently I am using DialogFlow ES. Implementing for whatsapp bot where user can reply back anytime to bot.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comment, the [DialogFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#table) quota for session is 30 minutes but `Context` is kept only for 20 minutes according to [Lifespan](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#lifespan) documentation.

> In addition, all contexts expire after 20 minutes of becoming active.

There was a similar thread on `Github`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/253). One of the comments contains a DialogFlow Support Team response.

> If you start testing your agent after a period of inactivity, it may need a couple of requests to "wake up". To make sure that the agent is always awake, you can send scheduled automated requests to it (simulating user queries), for example, every 10-20 minutes. If you have webhook enabled in your agent, make sure that these requests hit your web service – this will ensure that your web service stays awake.

Similar solution was used in another stack question, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60757133/11148139)

> I did,i stored the dialog flow response context in db , and sent the last context stored in db with the request to dialogflow detectIntent after 30 min. and it worked fine

There is also a guide about extending Dialogflow session - [Extending context duration in Dialogflow](https://botflo.com/extending-context-duration-in-dialogflow/)

The last thing I want to mention, that there is a feature for [Long-lasting sessions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/session#long-lasting), but it's for `DialogFlow CX` not for `DialogFlow ES`.